# Gradle can not build with lombok

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

Currently can not build a new project with Gradle and Lombok.

```
warning: You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
  Your processor is: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.IncrementalProcessingEnvironment
  Lombok supports: sun/apple javac 1.6, ECJ
/Users/rich/Desktop/reports/src/main/java/com/example/reports/reportparamters/ReportParameter.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
        filter.setReportParameter(this);
```

I know this was a common issues with older versions of gradle and lombok and have seen similar questions on this site, however I'm using more recent version and could not get passed this issue

**Environment info**

- Java: openjdk 13.0.1 2019-10-15 (This is the OpenJ9 version and NOT the HotSpot version)
- Javac: 13.01
- Gradle: 6.0.1
- Lombok: 1.18.10

Build.gradle (Built using [Spring initialiser](https://start.spring.io/))

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '13'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

**Things I've tried**

- I've tried swapping out deps for the Lombok gradle plugin, as stated [here](https://start.spring.io/) :
- Nearly all other similar issues on stack overflow simply referred to updating Gradle to a version 4.5+ and a Lombok version of 1.18+

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue right now with OpenJ9 13.0.1.9, but it works fine with Zulu Java 13 (zulu13.29.9-ca-jdk13.0.2-win_x64).

So, I'm using Zulu when building with Gradle (6.0.1), and Open J9 to run my executable JAR.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it seems to be a bug related to OpenJ9.

The solution was to use the latest edge version, as commented below.
https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2501#issuecomment-664330803